# How to let perf stat support hardware event like "branches", "branch-misses" in KVM

Tags: performance, kvm, perf

I want to evaluate the performance of one process by "branch-misses" hardware event. But when I used perf stat to get "branch-misses" data, it always return 0 just because my os is in KVM. 
Because it's trouble for me to get one real machine to do the test. So I want to know that is there any method to get "branch-misses" by "perf stat" when I am in KVM. 
I'm really need your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it returning 0 or does it say "not supported" ? Also can you show how you run `perf stat` command ? And also provide the output of running `perf stat` please.

Comment: Also what happens when you run `perf stat ls` ?

Comment: I have tried "perf stat ls". the result is : all the "hardware event" value is zero and the "software event" have value

Comment: Can you share the output of ```dmesg | grep PMU``` ?

Comment: execute "dmesg| grep PMU" is nothing to output. For this question， I've searched a lot of information. I think that if we want perf support hardware event sample:
The solution: in KVM Host machine to open vPMU in KVM host.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/sect-virtualization_tuning_optimization_guide-monitoring_tools-vpmu
 But it's impossbile for us to access KVM host because I was in cloud machine in aws. 
I don't know I was right or not.  Hope to get your suggestion.